# Can Alien AI of other galaxy reach us?

Tags: aliens, artificial-intelligence

Is it possible for a Alien AI of other planet reach us for some reason.
Will they try to contact us ?

Comment: Is your question regarding alien planets, as suggested by your question, or alien galaxies, as suggested by its title? In case you're talking about galaxies you might want to differenciate between andromeda, which is (relatively) close and going to merge with ours, and other galaxies which are farther away and eventually will become unreachable even at the speed of light if the expansion of the universe keeps up. You should also explain the thought process regarding your differentiation between alien and alien AI.

Comment: Are you asking if the AI *could* reach us, or if they *would*? Either way, without more information this question is much too broad.

Comment: Hi, Amruth. It seems that your three questions have all been closed, and one has been automatically deleted. I noticed that they all seem to be about the real world; as the [tour] and [help] say, we're a site for building fictional worlds, generally to be used in stories, games, etc. All the questions you asked were closed for different reasons - Too Broad or Opinion-Based - so I would recommend trying to edit them, as per the text on the banner above, or trying differently in the future - making sure your questions are on-topic for the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galaxies are separated by vast amount of void. Closest galaxy, which happens to be dwarf galaxy, is 70000 light years away from us. This means, if they have sent a message it would take 70000 years to reach to us. They could try to send out signal saying that we are not alone. This could happen if the AI scans generic organic life form behaviour which wants to learn if they are alone in the universe. AI can also derive that other life forms could be search for aliens and thus would like to learn that they exists. Apart from that, there can basically be no useful communication that can be made to another galaxy. A round trip of hello would take 140000 years. That is a lot of time.

A final remark: this closest galaxy is orbiting around Milky Way and is currently being ripped apart, I think that this unstable galaxy would not be able to produce intelligent life forms that could create sentient AI. Closest stable-ish galaxy is 1.2 million light years away!